# Exibir uma Imagem através de URL

Tags: android, imagem, listview

Tenho uma imagem no link `http://187.45.142.241:8080/umamaoNovo/images/u184Tulips.jpg`

Gostaria de saber se tira alguma função para exibir rápido pós preciso exibir imagens em uma ListView.

Answer (score 2):

Você tem algumas opções de como implementar essa funcionalidade no seu projeto.

A primeira (a que eu particularmente prefiro) é utilizando o [Universal Image Loader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader), uma biblioteca super fácil de implementar e você consegue implementar somente lendo a documentação. Se estiver com dificuldade, há diversos tutoriais.

A segunda é utilizando o [ImageLoader e NetworkImageView do Volley](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/request.html). É bem tranquilo de implementar também, com a documentação oficial você consegue facilmente.

Comment: Tem também a lib https://github.com/square/picasso bem simples de implementar, tenho um exemplo que implementei:
https://github.com/analistacarlosh/listViewAndroidWebService