# Converter uma imagem em bitmap a patir de uma URL e setar em uma ImageView

Tags: android, listview, bitmap

Bom gostaria de saber como faço pra setar um URL em uma variável ImageView, não sei se fui claro?

```
  private final DisplayImageOptions options;

public NoticiasAdapter(Activity activity, List objects) {
    super(activity, R.layout.noticia_list_item , objects);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.stocks = objects;

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
    .cacheInMemory(true)
    .cacheOnDisk(true)
    .build();
}


public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rowView = convertView;
    StockQuoteView sqView = null;

    if(rowView == null)
    {

        LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
        rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.noticia_list_item, null);


        sqView = new StockQuoteView();
         //sqView.quote = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_symbol);
        sqView.ticker = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ticker_price);
        sqView.img  = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.img);     

        rowView.setTag(sqView);
    } else {
        sqView = (StockQuoteView) rowView.getTag();
    }



    Noticias currentStock = (Noticias) stocks.get(position);
    String imagem3 = currentStock.getImagem();

    sqView.ticker.setText(currentStock.getTitulo());
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imagem3, sqView.img, options);
  return rowView;
}

protected static class StockQuoteView {
    protected TextView ticker;
    protected TextView quote;
    protected ImageView img;
}
```

Comment: Você quer um ImageView que carregue imagens de URLs da internet?

Comment: É isso mesmo...

Comment: Olá, essa pergunta já foi feita e respondida aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/39883/exibir-uma-imagem-atrav%C3%A9s-de-url/39895#39895

Comment: Olá, eu vi a resposta, acho que a resposta que me deram ficou mais clara, não?

Comment: @Gustavo elaborei uma resposta que pode te ajudar!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o Universal Image Loader, que faz todo o trabalho pesado para você de uma forma rápida e eficaz.

Para implementa-la em seu projeto é simples:

1) Baixe o .jar [neste link](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) e importe na pasta "libs" de seu projeto

2) Em sua `Application` (se você não tiver uma, [veja como criar aqui](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html)) dentro do método `onCreate`, inicialize as configurações do `ImageLoader`:

```
...

ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(this)
        .threadPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY - 2)
        .threadPoolSize(3)
        .diskCacheExtraOptions(480, 320, null)
        .tasksProcessingOrder(QueueProcessingType.LIFO)
        .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

...
```

3) Para implementar dentro de uma `ListView`, por exemplo, configure seu `Adapter` da seguinte maneira:

```
private final DisplayImageOptions options;

public SeuAdapter (List<SeusObjetos> list){
    ...

    options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true)
        .cacheOnDisk(true)
        .build();
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    ...
    String suaUrl = "algumaUrl";
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(suaUrl, suaImageView, options);
    ...

    return convertView;

}
```

Claro que, você irá fazer as implementações que atendem suas necessidades no `DisplayImageOptions`. Explore a documentação dessa biblioteca para entender e implementar o que melhor te atende

Comment: Obrigado, vou tentar oq vc sugeriu também...

Comment: Está pedindo que eu criae estas classes: ImageLoaderConfiguration,QueueProcessingType e ImageLoader..Está certo é necessário, ou fiz algo de errado?

Comment: Você colocou a biblioteca no projeto? Importou as classes certas na sua Application?

Comment: A tela fica branca, nem os títulos e nem as imagens, você tem ideia do que poderia estar dando erro?

Answer (score 2):

Esta é uma forma simples e direta de realizar o procedimento solicitado.

**1 - Crie uma pasta onde ficarão as suas imagens, ponha esse código na atividade principal:**

```
if (Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED)){
             File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+File.separator+"/MeuApp/imagens/");
                directory.mkdirs();

        }
```

---

**2 - Crie um método privado chamado getBitmapFromURL, para "pegar" a imagem a partir de uma url:**

```
private Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url) {
    try {
        URL src = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) src.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**3 - Crie um método que receberá o Bitmap convertido para salvar no seu dispositivo:**

```
private void salvando(Bitmap abmp){

    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
            "/MeuApp/imagens/";
            File dir = new File(file_path);
            if(!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
            File file = new File(dir, "nomedaImagembaixada");
            FileOutputStream fOut;
            try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            ;
            abmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 85, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }


}
```

---

**4 - Este código executará o download, pois passará um retorno para o método `salvando()`:**

```
salvando(getBitmapFromURL(www.meusite.com.br/imagens/minhaimagens.png));
```

---

**5 - AGORA SIM VOCÊ TEM UMA URI!**

```
Uri imagemURI = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/MeuApp/imagens/" + "nomedaImagembaixada" );
```

---

**6 - Enfim o que você queria na ImageView:**

```
imgview.setImageUri(imagemURI);
```

---

```
OBS: Caso queira mais de uma imagem: Substitua a 'nomedaImagembaixada' por uma variável do tipo STRING e a 'www.meusite.com.br/imagens/minhaimagens.png', TAMBÉM. Assim, cada valor dado, a ambas as variáveis, servirão para gerar novas imagens.
```

Comment: Deu certo??????

Comment: Não tenho como testar no momento, mas vou fazer isso, muito obrigado = D

Comment: Qualquer dúvida, posta aqui no comentário, pois é preciso mais algumas coisas, mas imagino que você saiba como fazer :)

Comment: Tudo bem, valeu :)

Comment: Como faço pra pegar as imagens e mostrar no ListView depois, já que elas terão nomes distintos...

Comment: Substitua a 'nomedaImagembaixada' por uma variável do tipo STRING e a 'www.meusite.com.br/imagens/minhaimagens.png', TAMBÉM. Assim, cada valor dado, a ambas as variáveis, servirão para gerar novas imagens.

Comment: Mas desse modo as imagens não ficariam todos com o mesmo nome, não tem problema?

Comment: Não ficarão com o mesmo nome se você utilizar uma lógica para variar esta variável do tipo String que citei, conforme cada ImageView :)

Comment: Não tem como eu te ajudar além disso sem entender o que você quer, mais aprofundadamente. Tenho que ver o layout, o objetivo do seu app...Você precisa colocar os códigos xml completo e etc...

Comment: Ahh certo, pensei em utilizar um contador e agregar o numero ao nome da imagem, mas estou com duvida se a variável não é destruída a cada chamada pelo ListView...

Comment: Aí você precisará criar uma posição para cada imagem. Criando um adaptador.

Comment: Os moderadores não gostam desse tipo de conversa que distorcem a resposta. Aconselho a você criar uma nova pergunta, INSERINDO TUDO QUE VOCÊ TEM DE CÓDIGO.

Comment: Tudo bem, vou criar outra pergunta inserindo o código...